# Angular page hangs probably due to high memory usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

i'm currently developing a project using Angular, MySQL, Express and Node-JS using Typescript. I have an Angular Component that what it does is that it loads a PrimeNG table with students data, that comes from an API to my Node.Js app server.

The table also has a delete and a edit option, the edit option pulls up a dialog in which the data of that certain student is loaded from the same data from the table, also on that same dialog, two dropdowns are filled with data that comes from API calls executed onInit().

My problem is that i implemented that the dropdowns filled in onInit dynamically by making API calls to my server, but when one function is called it hangs the whole app, even my computer almost hangs. I don't know how to optimize it, or if i'm doing it the wrong way.

Here is some of my component code

```
   ngOnInit() {
    this.estudiantesService.getEstudiantes().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.estudiantes = res; //Data of the students for the table
      },
      err => console.error(err)
    );

     this.cargaDropdownSeccion(); //Loads data for dropdown, doesn't hang the app but is probably because at the time it only brings a single record
     this.cargaDropdownEspecialidades(); //Loads data for dropdown, this hangs the whole thing by itself, it usually brings seven records from the db
  }



   cargaDropdownSeccion() {
    this.seccionDrpdwn = [];
    this.seccionDrpdwn.push({ label: 'Secciones', value: null });

    this.seccionesService.getSecciones().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.secciones = res;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.secciones.length; i++) {
          this.seccionDrpdwn.push({ label: this.secciones[i].seccion, value:        this.secciones[i].idSeccion });
        }
      },
      err => console.error(err)
    );
  }

  cargaDropdownEspecialidades() {
    this.especialidadDrpdwn = [];
    this.especialidadDrpdwn.push({ label: 'Especialidad', value: null });
    console.log('aqui');
    this.especialidadesService.getEspecialidades().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.especialidades = res;
        console.log('sigo aqui');
        for (let i = 0; i < this.especialidades.length; i++) {
          this.especialidades.push({ label: this.especialidades[i].especialidad, value: this.especialidades[i].idEspecialidad });
        }
      },
      err => console.error(err)
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

With each push to `this.especialidades` you increase `this.especialidades.length` which essentialy makes the loop infinite.

Try this instead:

```
this.especialidadesService.getEspecialidades().subscribe(
  res => {
    this.especialidades = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
      this.especialidades.push({ label: res[i].especialidad, value: res[i].idEspecialidad });
    }
  },
  err => console.error(err)
);
```

Comment: I can't use res.length because length is not a property of res

Comment: Well if `res` does not have `length` property then `this.especialidades` also does not have the property `length` since you assign `res` to `this.especialidades` in your code `this.especialidades = res;` and yet you use it in the for loop `for (let i = 0; i < this.especialidades.length; i++)` so that doesn't make sense. What do you expect the `res` variable to be and what is it actualy?

Answer (score 1):

As bojack said there will be infinite loop formed, so to aviod this change the below code

```
this.especialidadesService.getEspecialidades().subscribe(
  res => {
    this.especialidades = res;
    console.log('sigo aqui');
    for (let i = 0; i < this.especialidades.length; i++) {
      this.especialidades.push({ label: this.especialidades[i].especialidad, value: this.especialidades[i].idEspecialidad });
    }
  },
  err => console.error(err)
);
```

TO

```
this.especialidadesService.getEspecialidades().subscribe(
  res => {
   this.especialidades = res;
   this.especialidades = this.especialidades.map((val)=>{
         return { label: val.especialidad, value: val.idEspecialidad }     
   })
  },
  err => console.error(err)
);
```